# Is $0$ an eigenvalue of an orthogonal projection if and only if $A \ne \operatorname{id}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb C$-Hilbert space and $A\in\mathfrak L(H)$ be an orthogonal projection. Is it true that

1. $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ iff $A\ne\operatorname{id}_H$?
2. $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ iff $A\ne0$?
3. $A$ is (strictly) positive iff $A=\operatorname{id}_H$?

Regarding 1: We know that $\mathcal N(A)=\mathcal R(A)^\perp$ and hence $\mathcal N(A)=\{0\}$ iff $\mathcal R(A)=H$? But does the latter necessarily imply $A=\operatorname{id}_H$?

Regarding 2: We know that $\mathcal N(1-A)=\mathcal R(A)$ and hence $\mathcal N(1-A)=\{0\}$ iff $\mathcal R(A)=\{0\}$. This clearly implies $A=0$.

Regarding 3: No idea how we can show that ...

Comment: For 3., doesn't strict positivity imply that $0$ cannot be an eigenvalue?

Answer (score 1):

1. If $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then find $x\in H$ non-zero such that $Ax=0$. Thus $A\ne 1$. Conversely, if $A\ne 1$ let $x\in H$ such that $Ax\ne x$, so $y:=(1-A)x\ne0$. But then $Ay=A(1-A)x=(A-A^2)x=(A-A)x=0$, so $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

2. Follows directly by applying (1) to the projection $1-A$.
3. If $A=1$, then obviously $A$ is strictly positive. Conversely, if $A$ is strictly positive, then $\langle Ax,x\rangle>0$ for all $x\ne0$, by definition. Note that $A=A^*$ and $A=A^2$, so $\langle Ax,x\rangle=\langle A^*Ax,x\rangle=\langle Ax,Ax\rangle=\|Ax\|^2$, so $\|Ax\|^2>0$ for all $x\ne 0$, i.e. $Ax\ne0$ for all $x\ne0$, so $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$. Applying (1) we conclude that $A=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If, as you say, (2.) directly follows by applying (1.) to $1-A$, couldn't we use my proof of (2.) (or is it wrong?) and obtain (1.) by applying (2.) to $A=1-(1-A)$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d yes, of course!